# How to delete multiple blob large objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, blob, postgresql-9.5

I have million of rows in pg_largeobject_metadata table I want to delete. What I have tried so far is :

- A simple select `lo_unlink(oid)` works fine
- A `perform lo_unlink(oid)` in a loop of 10000 rows will also work fine
- So when I delete recursively multiple rows i get this error. I cannot increase `max_locks_per_transaction` because it is managed by AWS.

> ERROR:  out of shared memory 
>   HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction. 
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT lo_unlink(c_row.oid)" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 21 at
>   PERFORM SQL state: 53200

Here is the program I tried to write but I still get the **Out of shared memory** ERROR.

```
DO $proc$
DECLARE
v_fetch     bigInt;
v_offset    bigInt;
nbRows      bigInt;
c_row       record;
c_rows      CURSOR(p_offset bigInt, p_fetch bigInt) FOR SELECT oid FROM pg_largeobject_metadata WHERE oid BETWEEN 1910001 AND 2900000 OFFSET p_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT p_fetch ROWS ONLY;

BEGIN
v_offset    := 0;
v_fetch     := 100;
select count(*) into nbRows FROM pg_largeobject_metadata WHERE oid BETWEEN 1910001 AND 2900000;
RAISE NOTICE 'End loop nbrows = %', nbRows;
LOOP                                        -- Loop the different cursors 
    RAISE NOTICE 'offseter = %', v_offset;          
    OPEN c_rows(v_offset, v_fetch);
    LOOP                                    -- Loop through the cursor results
        FETCH c_rows INTO c_row;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        perform lo_unlink(c_row.oid);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_rows;
    EXIT WHEN  v_offset > nbRows;
    v_offset := v_offset + v_fetch;         -- The next 10000 rows
END LOOP;
END;
$proc$;
```

I am using Pg 9.5
Can anyone has faced this issue and could help please?

Answer (score 2):

Each `lo_unlink()` grabs a lock on the object it deletes. These locks are freed only  at the end of the transaction, and they are capped by `max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)` (see [Lock Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-locks.html)). By default `max_locks_per_transaction` is 64, and cranking it up by several order of magnitudes is not a good solution.

The typical solution is to move the outer LOOP from your DO block into your client-side code, and commit the transaction at each iteration (so each transaction removes 10000 large objects and commits).

Starting with PostgreSQL version 11, a COMMIT inside the [DO block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) would be possible, just like transaction control in procedures is possible.